# Incoming int is undefned in a function that has int parameter (Golang)

Tags: function, go, integer

I am trying to insert the first item in a Linked List in Golang.

For some reason, the int I have defined as the incoming parameter is undefined. When I run the following code in Go Playground, I get:

*./prog.go:15:36: undefined: Value*

*./prog.go:16:11: undefined: Value*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


// Definition for singly-linked list.
type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}

func insert_first (LL ListNode, int Value) *ListNode {
   LL.Val = Value
   LL.Next = nil
   return &LL
}


func main() {

    var foo_list *ListNode
    
    foo_list = insert_first (foo_list, 300)

    fmt.Println(foo_list.Val, foo_list.Next)

}
```

Comment: It should be `Value int`, not `int Value`

Comment: Thank you for quick response. That worked. Please add this as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Make sure to pay close attention to the line numbers when reading an error message.  You'll notice that the first error occurs on the `func` line, i.e. the line that the function is declared on, meaning that it is complaining before you even try to use the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, types come after variable names.

```
func insert_first (LL ListNode, int Value) *ListNode {
```

should be

```
func insert_first (LL ListNode, Value int) *ListNode {
```